# R Error: Aesthetics must be valid data columns. Problematic aesthetic(s)

Tags: r

Have been running the following code, but getting the error as mentioned in title. Please help.

```
set.seed(1234)
title_word_pairs %>%
  filter(n >= 1000) %>%
  graph_from_data_frame() %>%
  ggraph(layout = "fr") +
  geom_edge_link(aes(edge_alpha = n, edge_width = n), edge_colour = "cyan4") +
  geom_node_point(size = 5) +
  geom_node_text(aes(label = name), repel = TRUE, 
                 point.padding = unit(0.2, "lines")) +
  ggtitle('Word network in Oppo Reno2 reviews')
theme_void()
```

I don't know how to automatically pick scale for object of type function. Defaulting to continuous.

Error:

```
Aesthetics must be valid data columns. Problematic aesthetic(s): edge_alpha = n, edge_width = n. Did you mistype the name of a data column or forget to add stat()?
```

Comment: Don't know how to automatically pick scale for object of type function. Defaulting to continuous.
Don't know how to automatically pick scale for object of type function. Defaulting to continuous.
Error: Aesthetics must be valid data columns. Problematic aesthetic(s): edge_alpha = n, edge_width = n. 
Did you mistype the name of a data column or forget to add stat()?

Comment: Have you found a solution to that so far?

Answer (score 0):

Could you provide some data with your example?  I got the same error in the context of fitting a SIR (Susceptible/Infected/Recovered) epidemiological compartmental model with the "fitR" package and solved it by explicitly specifying that the R object was a data frame. This code produced the error:

```
 > X1 <- cbind(time = X$index, I = X$y)
 > plotTraj(data = X1, time.column = "time") 
 Don't know how to automatically pick scale for object of type function. Defaulting to continuous. Error: Aesthetics must be valid data columns. Problematic aesthetic(s): x = time.  Did you mistype the name of a data column or forget to add after_stat()?
```

This code produced a plot:

```
X1 <- data.frame(cbind(time = X$index, I = X$y))
plotTraj(data = X1, time.column = "time")
```